# How to display number of records every month according to datetime format c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am currently trying to display a record in my form with a sql database table called "Registration" 2 column. Information will be display in gridview

Below is the table:

```
Registration ID           Date Registered
    1                          10/4/2013
    2                          11/4/2013
    3                          12/5/2013
    4                          13/6/2013
```

Result will be:

```
Number of record           Month Registered
2                          April
1                          May
1                          June
```

Do anyone know what the query is?

Comment: try to get result from sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
Select Count(*)  As NumberOfRecord, DATENAME(month, DateRegistered) As MonthRegistered  
from TableName GRoup by DATENAME(month, DateRegistered)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try SQL something like below to retrive data

```
select  count(*) as Numberofrecord, datename(month, DateRegistered) as MonthRegistered 
from table
group by datename(month, DateRegistered)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select count(*) as NumberOfRegister,DATENAME(MONTH,DateRegisterd)  as MonthRegistered 
from table_name
group by  DATENAME(MONTH,DateRegisterd)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get records from SQL, then try something like this

```
SELECT MONTH(DateRegisterd) MONTH, COUNT(*) COUNT
FROM YourTableName
WHERE YEAR(DateRegisterd)=2013//If you want records of particular year
GROUP BY MONTH(DateRegisterd)
```

OR like  this

```
select  count(*) as Numberofrecord, datename(month, Date_Registered) as MonthRegistered 
from YourTable group by datename(month, Date_Registered)
```